# Using pip with pip-installed mercurial

Tags: python, mercurial, installation, pip

So I installed Mercurial with:

```
pip install mercurial
```

Now, when I am doing:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get:

```
> Cannot find command 'hg'
```

Is there any way to make pip use `c:\python27\scripts\hg.bat` as the hg command? I can run it simply by typing hg, so I assumed that pip would also.

I did try using:

```
mklink c:\windows\system32\hg.bat c:\python27\scripts\hg.bat
```

And:

```
mklink c:\windows\system32\hg.exe c:\python27\scripts\hg.bat
```

Neither with any affect.

I have looked elsewhere on Google, and every answer concerning hg assumes that you've either used apt-get or the installer to get Mercurial installed.

If there is a way to use the mercurial available with pip, I'm thinking that the initial setup of any Windows development environment would go quicker.

I am using Windows 7 (32-bit Python 2.7.10).

Thanks in advance for any help.